# I need check inputs/outputs with proc_open

Tags: php, stream, fread, proc-open

#Scenario:

I'm executing codes in python by proc_open, using py.exe.

Ex:

```
proc_open('py.exe file.py', $descriptorspec, $pipes, null, null)
```

My python code can have input or outputs in a undefined sequence.

Ex:

```
a = input('insert a value')
print(a)
```

or

```
print('Hello, this is a program!')
input('insert a value')
```

#Outputs:

To get outputs I'm using fread.

#Inputs:

To get inputs I'm using fwrite.

#Problem:

Since I have an undefined sequence in python code, I don't know if my program (python code) expect
an input or an output. If my program expect a input and I execute fread (output) command, my PHP will enter in a looping... waiting for nonexistent python output.

#Question

I can check in "pipes" if my python aplication is waiting a input or a output?

P.S: If it is not possible, how a can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is apparently no native solution to the problem. For now, I am attaching a non-printable character (0) to the user input.

original print: `input("enter with one number")`

modified print: `input(chr (0) + "enter with one number")`

In this way I can use a flag (out/in)

;)